# How to get instance name in Abaqus Python?

Tags: python, macros, abaqus

I'm still quite new to Abaqus scripting and right now I'm trying to create Abaqus macros to optimize the workflow of simulating leaf spring assemblies since some assemblies can sometimes have up to 40 parts that need to be renamed according to their position (leaf-1, leaf-2, silencer-1, etc). However, the problem is that the number suffix of the default names (Part-1, Part-2, etc) given by Abaqus when importing the parts don't always correspond to the part's position in the assembly, hence the current workflow is to select the part's instance in assembly, see where they are located then change the part's name accordingly. This is a very repetitive and tedious work that involves a lot of clicking.

So I've managed to make a macro to rename the parts that prompt the user's input, but I just can't seem to find any code or method to get the **selected Instance's name**. I've dug through the Abaqus Scripting Guide but found nothing too.

Perhaps someone here has any idea?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if it is possible to change the feature name by simply changing its appropriate attribute, so here is the long way to do your renaming:

```py
m = mdb.models['My-Model']
a = m.rootAssembly

for part_inst in a.instances:
    # Actual name
    old_name = part_inst.name
    
    # Here you add your code to somehow highlight the part instance and
    # to ask the user for an appropriate name
    # <...>
    
    # Rename the instance
    a.instances.changeKey(
        fromName=old_name, toName=new_name
    )
```

[Here you can find a corresponding documentation entry](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/cmd/default.htm?startat=pt02ch05s03.html#cmd-int-acl-types-repositories).

---

##### Edit

To highlight the instances you can:

1. Loop through instances using `for part_inst in a.instances` (as shown above);
2. Use the [`highlight()/unhighlight()`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch11pyc01.html#ker-obj-canvas-commands-highlight-pyc) method of the Abaqus python library.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but I already got the code to change instance names. However, the current workflow is that the user has to type in the old name first then the new name, and doing it for 40 something parts isn't exactly practical, that's why I want to get the name of the selected instance if possible.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer